# Angular 301 redirect on dynamic URL?

Tags: angular, server

In my case my Url is Dynamic so how can I know that my original Url is correct or incorrect. What is the appropriate solution to tackle this problem?

the correct Url where 200 document call is getting updated:

```
http://localhost:4000/article/news-top-story/bharat-highways-invit-files-drhp-to-launch-rs-crore-ipo-1671794340325_1.html
```

the incorrect Url where i want to perform 301 redirection but my URL params are dynamic

```
http://localhost:4000/article/news-top-story/bharat-highways-invit-files-drhp-to-launch-rs-crore-ipo-1671794340325000000_1.html
```

My server.ts code looks like this

```
if(req.originalUrl === 'old-url-example'){
   res.redirect(301, '/top-share-market-news/1');
}else{
   res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  }
```

Comment: Please don't post the same text several times. Anyone trying to read your question will definitely not appreciate to have to go through the same thing many times trying to figure out if it's the same thing or not.

Comment: Also, is the difference with your urls really just additional `000000`?